# How to stop the Jupyter Server inside a Pycharm notebook

Tags: pycharm

A jupyter notebook is out to lunch: how can I stop it - short of restarting Pycharm?  The `interrupt kernel` lightning icon does nothing.

[image]

The last two cells look like this: we can see the last one is hanging:

[image]

I do not think this is related .. but in any case: The warning

> Notebook kernel doesn't match project interpreter

has been "addressed" many times already by clicking on

> Register project interpreter as kernel.

This also does not have any effect: the top banner bar goes away for a few seconds but then comes back at next attempt to run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open **Jupyter** tool window -> **Server Log** -> **Stop Jupyter Server**

[image]

> Notebook kernel doesn't match project interpreter

Should be addressed by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34160 I believe.